# Failed to load url ./Utils

Tags: tinymce, svelte, vite, sveltekit

'm encountering an issue with the TinyMCE Svelte package. When I try to run my project, I get the following error:
`Failed to load url ./Utils (resolved id: ./Utils) in X:/codeX3/CrimsonLotus_web/node_modules/@tinymce/tinymce-svelte/dist/ts/component/Editor.svelte. Does the file exist?`

Context:
I'm using the following versions:

Node.js: 18.15.0
npm: 9.5.0
@tinymce/tinymce-svelte: 1.0.1

Is this a known issue and is there a fix for it?
Is there something wrong with my setup that might be causing this?
Could this be a bug in the package?
that was working ok and i didn't change anything related

Answer (score 0):

The problem was vscode automatically added this import to my code

```
import { value } from '@tinymce/tinymce-svelte/dist/ts/component/Editor.svelte';
```

I don't believe how much time I wasted to find it